# ExpressJS Applying middleware only to routes in router

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have app where I have public routes and authorized routes. Public routes should go through auth as well, but if auth fails, it doesn't matter.

So I have two routers:

```
var publicRoutes = express.Router();
var secretRoutes = express.Router();

publicRoutes
    .use(auth)
    .use(ignoreAuthError);

publicRoutes.get('/public', function(req, res){
    res.status(200).send({message: "public"});
}); 

secretRoutes
    .use(auth)
    .use(handleAuthError);

secretRoutes.get('/secret', function(req, res){
    res.status(200).send({message: "secret"});
}); 

...

app.use(publicRoutes);
app.use(secretRoutes);
```

Now everything works fine, but if I change the order of `app.use` public routes throw auth error. Also I cannot get any 404, 500 etc errors, because they all go through auth errors.

So obviously what is happening is that `Router.use()` is being applied to all routes with the same root - in this case `"/"`

Therefore I think if I would use just `auth` middleware on all routes and then add other middlewares directly to routes it should work fine. But it kind of brakes the point of having multiple Routers for me.

I would expect that if I use `Router.use()` the middleware will apply only if that particular router matches any routes it has set up, instead of changing behavior of other router.

Do I understand this correctly? Is there any way to handle this without actually having to add middleware to every single route?

Comment: This is just how express routers work -- it's based on the route namespace. Try `app.use("/public", publicRoutes); app.use("/secret", secretRoutes)`

Comment: @ExplosionPills yes but then I would have to base all routes on these namespaces. So all routes would be `/secret/something` etc, which is not desirable.

Comment: I understand, but I think this is just a limitation with Express. Maybe someone else has a better solution, though.

Comment: Yes I understand, unfortunately this seems to be quite a let down, because if I do `app.use()` instead of `router.use()` it will have effectively the same result and routers become strictly a way for me to categorize routes rather than something functional. Just seem as a unnecessary limitation.

Comment: Actually there is exactly the same discussion going on at expressjs issues on github - https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2760

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, solved thanks to @Explosion Pills comment.

**Bad:**

```js
app.use(secretRoutes); // router.use calls won't be scoped to "/secret" 
app.use(publicRoutes); // public routes will be impacted
```

**Good:**

```js
app.use("/secret", secretRoutes); // router.use calls will be scoped to "/secret" 
app.use("/public", publicRoutes); // public routes won't be impacted
```